# How to create a command in Latex that return a letter in a different formatting?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to change the font for writing some letters in different formatting in equations (math environment), but, couldn't do so correctly.

I was thinking of creating a new command for each specific letter that I will use, or, to create a local environment with a different formatting. Specifically, I'm interest in using different formats for greek letters, like the "Antykwa Torunska text and math (\usepackage[math]{anttor})" that appears in Figure 8 (page 9) in this [file](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf).

The examples that I saw doesn't tackle this type of problem.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Do you want to use one font, say computer modern, in your document but change the whole Greek alphabet to Antykwa?

Comment: I wanted to use a 'default font' (let's say computer modern), but, also, have more symbols available, that is, more than a greek alphabet style at my disposal. I guess the solution that @egreg point out will suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new symbol font for the Antikwa Toruńska math Greek letters and specific commands.

However, the font should probably be scaled down to match the standard font.

```
\documentclass{article}

% relevant lines from omsantt.fd
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{antt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{antt}{m}{it}{<-> s*[0.9] mi-anttri}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{antt}{b}{it}{<-> s*[0.9] mi-anttbi}{}

% declare a symbol font
\DeclareSymbolFont{anttletters}{OML}{antt}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{anttletters}{bold}{OML}{antt}{b}{it}

% copied (with obvious changes) from fontmath.ltx
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atalpha}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atbeta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atgamma}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atdelta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atepsilon}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atzeta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ateta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\attheta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atiota}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atkappa}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atlambda}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atmu}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atnu}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atxi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atpi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atrho}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atsigma}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\attau}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atupsilon}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atphi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atchi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atpsi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atomega}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvarepsilon}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvartheta}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvarpi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvarrho}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvarsigma}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\atvarphi}{\mathord}{anttletters}{"27}

\begin{document}

$\atalpha+\atbeta+\atgamma+\atdelta+\atepsilon+\atzeta+\ateta+\attheta+\atkappa+\atlambda+\atmu$

$\atnu+\atxi+\atpi+\atrho+\atsigma+\attau+\atupsilon+\atphi+\atchi+\atpsi+\atomega$

$\atvarepsilon+\atvartheta+\atvarphi+\atvarrho+\atvarsigma+\atvarphi$

$\alpha+\atalpha$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much.